# Passing string to setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

**WAIT BEFORE REPORTING!!!** I read everything about "passing parameter with setOnClickListener", but I didn't found a solution to my problem.

```
String citazione = new String(data[position]);
share_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, citazione);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, v.getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
    }
});
```

I should put the string "citazione" in the 6 line, but I can't edit `View v` because I'm using it in the 8 line.
I tried everithing (`getContext()`, `startActivity()`, the `v` before) but nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? I mean, what isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it final:

```
final String citazione = new String(data[position]);
```

Comment: Yep, it's quite simple. I recommend you to read the section "Final and inner classes" here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29. You should always declare your variables as final if you want to use them at the anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would declare the onClick in the XML like so:

```
<Button 
...
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
....
/>
```

Then I would make citazione a class variable

```
private String citazione;
```

The buttons onClick in the activity would be

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    //do what you want here with citazione
}
```